# Python regex to find the consecutive links

Tags: python, regex, python-requests

So I want to find all the links from a website one after the other
ex.
"https://vit.ac.in" then "https://vit.ac.in/questions/" then "https://vit.ac.in/questions/ask/" something like this

and make a table out of it.
I am using requests module to get the html content of a website using

```
x = requests.get('https://vit.ac.in')
links = re.findall("href=[\"\'](h.*?)[\"\']", x.text)
```

This gives me a list with all the links. Now I want to display the links in levels as shown above using regex. Cant use beautiful soup and other modules because our sir has asked us to do it with just regex

Comment: If the thing you are looking for is an *ordering* of the results you've found and I am assuming that a) that is not just the order the links were found in the page and b) by your examples you want them to be displayed based on page hierarchy order, then is it not just alphabetical order? Then `/` would come first and `/questions` next and `/questions/ask` and if there was another `/subpage` and `/subpage/subsubpage` they'd be in the right depth-first order too.

Comment: The python package `urllib` may help you a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would make it easy to import as a csv, with one level per column:

```
import re
import requests

x = requests.get('https://vit.ac.in')
links = re.findall("href=[\"\'](h.*?)[\"\']", x.text)

links = set(map(lambda x: x.strip('/'), links)) # stripping '/' and removing duplicates
links = sorted(list(links))         # sorting alphabetically

base_url = links[0]
for li in links:
    if li.find(base_url) == 0:
        # we are looking how "deep" the link is in comparison to base_url
        print((len(li.split('/'))-len(base_url.split('/'))) * "\t," + li)
    else:
        base_url = li
        print(li)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Data type of links is a list , Try sorting list based on length

```
sorted_list = sorted(links, key=len)
print(sorted_list)
```